# FragmentTransactions null pointer exception

Tags: android, fragment

When I try to get a SupportMapFragment from a fragment that I have already added and commited to my activity, I get a NPE sometimes. For example, if my code is like:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, fragmentMapa).commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }

    ... //non-related code...

    setMapFragment();
}


setMapFragment(){
    mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}
```

I get a NPE in the `mapa`line of code. Thats weird cause if I move the `mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager...` line to a `onPostExecute()` method of an asyncTask (wich takes like 1 or 2 seconds) it works properly, so I think that the transaction takes a few seconds in execute. That's why I am using `executePendingTransactions()` but looks like it does nothing.

How should I work with fragments to avoid this NPE when the transactions have not already finished?

Answer (score 0):

You should setMapFragment on your Fragment that you open. Call

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

to access your fragment manager from your Fragment andalso do

```
setMapFragment(){
    mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) yourFragmentView.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
}
```

Comment: When you said "yourFragmentView" you meant "yourFragmentManager"? I am trying to do it but I am still getting NPE: FragmentManager fm = HomeActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager(); mapa =((SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

Comment: The weird thing anyway is that it works perfectly if I get the map later in the code

Comment: No, in your fragment inside onCreateView you have a view where you inflate your xml that contains map object, to findViewById you need to do like i said